# No JPEG decoder found in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders() on Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, jpeg

I'm trying to limit the size of image uploads by changing their resolution, but even if I don't change the resolution on a JPEG, for instance, the resulting image is over twice the size of the original despite being the same dpi, depth and resolution.

I'm using the Graphics.FromImage(bitmap) method and then attempting to "compress" the image using the approach prescribed by [Microsoft help docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882583(v=vs.110).aspx). I'm not sure if it's because I'm on Windows Server 2012, but the list of decoders returned by `ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders()` does not contain a JPEG decoder.

Not sure if it should make a difference that I'm on Windows Server 2012, but I would think this would be something that's available by default.

I can't seem to find much documentation on this so I'm hoping someone out there can provide some guidance or point me in the direction of an open source alternative I could use here. I know Photoshop can do an amazing job at turning high res images into excellent quality images that are way way smaller than the original... there has to be some half decent library out there! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you need to explicitly [install the Windows Media Player package](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/a816bbdc-5a9c-4cf9-aa8c-090a61da3e3a/need-to-install-windows-media-player-on-windows-server-2012-release-candidate-many-apps-requires?forum=winserver8gen)?

Comment: maybe, but I'd rather use a third party library over complicating the deployment process